# Expiration date in Amazon s3: How to set a dynamic trigger?

Tags: amazon-web-services, permissions, amazon-s3

I´ve managed to create a bucket in my Amazon s3 account, and I´ve added to it a couple of files.
I´ve downloaded CloudBerry Explorer (the freeware edition), and I´ve uploaded a file and set it as private with an expiration date.

This is what my link looks like:

```
http://dja61b1p3y3bp.cloudfront.net/taller_parte1.flv?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIEZ23XILJFNS3ZVA&Expires=1379991642&Signature=GrBLzn13nkm8NiU6JXBj0jC0i%2F8%3D
```

The thing is that this is an "static" expiration date, **it has a one week expiration date counting it from now**.
I mean, If I have an online course, and I receive every week different students, and I want to set that course and use that file, I should go and update that expiration date every single week.

Is there any way to configure the file to expire a week later counting that period of time from the click that has made each individual user?

How may I do that?

Thanks for your insight!

Comment: You can generate the URL on-the-fly and set the expiration to one week in the future: http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/s3-developer-guide/RESTAuthentication.html